SwiftUI/UIKit - Bottom Sheet Drop back on Smaller Detents
I want to know how this effect is achieved in SwiftUI or UIKit.
https://streamable.com/hvo8k7
I did some tests using the SwiftUI bottom sheet:
var body: some View {
    Button("Toggle") {
        showingCredits.toggle()
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showing) {
        Text("Test sheet")
            .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
    }
}

The "drop back" only occurs, if the bottom sheet reaches the "large" presentation detend. But my question is how to achieve this "drop back" on different detents but large.

This will work with non-large presentation sheets:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showingCredits = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button("Toggle") {
                    showingCredits.toggle()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .customSheet(isPresented: $showingCredits) {
            Text("Test sheet")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

struct CustomSheet<Destination: View>: ViewModifier {
    
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @ViewBuilder var destination: () -> Destination
    
    @State private var scale: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
    @State private var cornerRadius: Double = 0.0
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(.background)
            .cornerRadius(cornerRadius)
            .scaleEffect(scale)
            .onChange(of: isPresented, { _, newValue in
                withAnimation {
                    scale = newValue ? CGSize(width: 0.95, height: 0.95) : CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
                    cornerRadius = newValue ? 15 : 0
                }
            })
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                destination()
                    .presentationDetents([.medium])
            }
            .background(.black)
    }
}

extension View {
    func customSheet<Destination: View>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder destination: @escaping () -> Destination) -> some View {
        modifier(CustomSheet(isPresented: isPresented, destination: destination))
    }
}



Thank you for your solution. Could you explain why there is a short delay after the sheet is closed and the view to switch back to their full size?

@Gamekohl It is because isPresented property is changed once the sheet is fully dismissed(i.e. removed from the screen), which invokes the onChange method
You can check this by adding a button inside your sheet and make it to toggle the property isPresented. You'll see that the view returns to its initial scale immediately after you press the button

Would it also be possible to get this effect by dismissing the sheet by swipe?

@Gamekohl Sure. By making a custom sheet, this way you would have full control of drag gesture.
